# How to stop the queuing of multiple animations based on occurrence jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

So, I have this webpage and I use this library called transit to animate 3d rotations and other css transformations.  I have three links which when the mouse hovers over them they are supposed to scale up 1.2 times.  It works, everything is fine and dandy, until I quickly run the mouse over the icon several times.  Instead of the animation just occurring once, it occurs several times in a row (or how many times I run my mouse over it).  How do I make it that no matter how many times the mouse is run over the div, it only animates once (like for a prolonged hover)?

Am I being clear?

Here the website link:
[LINK](http://mechadogs.org/first)

Here's the jquery code:

```
//FYI, the div id is "rotater"    
$(function(){  // $(document).ready shorthand
                $('#background').hide(); 
                $( "#banner").hide();
                $( "#rotater").hide();
                $( ".tab" ).hide();
                $( ".content" ).hide();
                $( "#share" ).hide();
                $( ".sidenav").hide();
                $("#navigation").animate({top:"100%"});
                window.setTimeout(function(){$('#banner').fadeIn('slow');$("#navigation").animate({top:"0"});
                                             $('#background').fadeIn('slow');
                                             $("#rotater").fadeIn("fast").transition({rotateY:360, duration:3000});
                                            $( "#share" ).fadeIn("slow");$(".sidenav").fadeIn("slow");
                                            $("#ha").animate({top:"25%",left:"3%"});$("#do").animate({top:"45%",left:"3%"});
                                            $("#set").animate({top:"65%",left:"3%"});$("#net").animate({top:"25%",left:"75%"});
                                            $("#dasu").animate({top:"65%",left:"75%"});}, 1000);
                $( ".sidenav" ).hover(function(){$("#"+this.id).transition({scale:1.2});}, function(){$("#"+this.id).transition({scale:1});}); // THIS IS THE CODE IN QUESTION
                $( "#share" ).hover(function(){$( "#share" ).animate({left:"0%"});}, function(){$( "#share" ).animate({left:"-15%"});});
                var cw = $('#rotater').width();
                $('#rotater').css({'height':cw+'px'});
                setInterval(function(){$("#rotater").transition({rotateY:'+=360deg', duration:3000});},10000);

            });
            $(window).load(function() {
               $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
            })
```

Comment: what is `.transition`? also dont do this `$("#"+this.id)` just do this `$(this)`

Comment: .transition is the custom animation library that I am using.  Works the same as animate().  Thanks for the other tip.

Comment: How "same" does it work as "animate()"? `animate()` adds entries to an fx queue that can be stopped on demand using the `.stop()` or `.finish()` methods. Does the same apply to `.transition`?

Comment: Btw, you can use multiple selectors for the `.hide()` statement, so you don't have to repeat the first few lines over and over again (with only a change in selector): `$('#background, #banner, #rotator, ...').hide()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want multiple jQuery animations to run sequentially, then you will want to call `$(yourObj).stop()` before starting each animation.  You can use the arguments to `.stop(a, b)` to control what exactly happens - whether the animation is just stopped where it is and the new one starts from there or whether it jumps to the end state before your next one starts, etc...

See the [jQuery doc for .stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) for more details.  Often, what you want is this:

```
$(yourObj).stop(true, true);
```

to jump the previous animation to its end state and clear it from the queue so the next one can start immediately as if the first one had already completed.  You will probably want to call this before every jQuery animation that could possibly be invoked again before the first one completes.

For example, you could change this:

```
$( "#share" ).hover(function(){
    $( "#share" ).animate({left:"0%"});
}, function(){
    $( "#share" ).animate({left:"-15%"});
});
```

to this:

```
$( "#share" ).hover(function(){
    $( "#share" ).stop(true, true).animate({left:"0%"});
}, function(){
    $( "#share" ).stop(true, true).animate({left:"-15%"});
});
```

In some cases, you don't want the 2nd argument to be set to `true` (so you might just want `.stop(true)` instead of `.stop(true, true)`.  You may want the current animation to just stop where it is and let the new animation pick it up from there - that really depends upon the specific operation and how you want it to behave.

Comment: Thank you soooooooo much!!  You are a miracle!